# multi extract values with JQ

Tags: json, linux, shell, jq

I have this JSON file :

```
{
  "range": "Sheet!A2:B100",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "customer1_name",
      "customer1@email.com",
      "customer1_phone",
      "customer1_city"
    ],
    [
      "customer2_name",
      "customer2@email.com",
      "customer2_phone",
      "customer2_city"
    ]
  ]
}
```

And, from a shell script, I would like to use JQ to extract every value for every block and assign them to some variables. here is expected result :

For this block :

```
    [
      "customer1_name",
      "customer1@email.com",
      "customer1_phone",
      "customer1_city"
    ],
```

Result should be like this :

```
VAR1 = "customer1_name"
VAR2 = "customer1@email.com"
VAR3 = "customer1_phone"
VAR4 = "customer1_city"
```

And for this block :

```
    [
      "customer2_name",
      "customer2@email.com",
      "customer2_phone",
      "customer2_city"
    ],
```

Result should be like this :

```
VAR1 = "customer2_name"
VAR2 = "customer2@email.com"
VAR3 = "customer2_phone"
VAR4 = "customer2_city"
```

The idea is to read JSON file block by block to get/retrieve all the values inside VARS.

Comment: I have found this : **jq -r '.values | .[1]'** but now how to extract values one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tr` like this is a bit hacky, but:

```
$ cat input

{
  "range": "Sheet!A2:B100",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "customer1_name",
      "customer1@email.com",
      "customer1_phone",
      "customer1_city"
    ],
    [
      "customer2_name",
      "customer2@email.com",
      "customer2_phone",
      "customer2_city"
    ]
  ]
}
$ jq -rc '.values[]' input | tr -d '["]' | while IFS=, read var1 var2 var3 var4; do echo "$var1 $var2 $var3 $var4"; done
customer1_name customer1@email.com customer1_phone customer1_city
customer2_name customer2@email.com customer2_phone customer2_city
```

You can also do:

```
$ jq -rc '.values[][]' input | while read name; read email; read phone; read city; do echo "$name $email $phone $city"; done;
customer1_name customer1@email.com customer1_phone customer1_city
customer2_name customer2@email.com customer2_phone customer2_city
```

Comment: quotes are missing here no ? **jq '-rc .values[][] input'**

Comment: sorry **jq '-rc .values[][]' input_file**

Comment: If you're going to use quotes, you should quote everything: `'jq' '-rc' '.values[][]' 'input'`.  No point in half measures.

Comment: But you certainly do *not* want `jq '-rc .values[][]'`, since `-rc` and `.values[][]` must be distinct arguments.

Comment: You do need to quote `.values[][]` if nullglob is set.

Comment: @Philippe, yes many thanks for this clarification indeed.